# phroute no encuentra rutas cuando ya existen dentro del objeto PHP

Tags: reactjs, axios, composer, php8

He usado **Phroute** como encargado de las solcitudes Http.
Mi problema radica en qué ya hay rutas definidas y cargadas en el objeto router, pero al intentar acceder a aquellas rutas simplemente entra a mi ruta por defecto de index.

Ejemplo:

Voy a enviar una solicitud post a 'https://mipage.com/autenticar/ingresar', el consumo de mi API lo estoy realizando en React JS mediante Axios.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function Axios() {
    const index = true;

    return axios.create({
        baseURL: !index ? 'http://localhost/project-php/' : 'https://mipage.com/'
    });
}
```

Función donde se realiza el consumo con Axios.

```
import React from "react";
import Axios from "../../../data/Axios";

class LoginAuth extends React.Component {

    getData(email, password) {
        const dtData = {
            user_data_email: email,
            user_data_password: password
        };

        Axios().post('autenticar/ingresar', dtData).then(response => {
            console.clear()
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }

}

export default new LoginAuth();
```

**web.php** que recibe la solicitud.

```
use App\Config\PHPRoute as Route;
use App\Models\Class\Request;
use App\Http\Middleware\UserAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Authentication\LoginController;

Route::sessions();
Route::fileGetContents();

Route::router([
    Route::newMiddleware('auth', UserAuth::class, 'auth'),
    Route::newMiddleware('no-auth', UserAuth::class, 'noAuth')
]);

Route::any("/", function() {
    Route::processOutput(
        new Request('warning', "Page not found")
    );
});

Route::middleware(['before' => "no-auth"], function() {
    Route::prefix('/autenticar', function() {
        Route::post('/ingresar', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
    });
});

Route::processOutput(Route::dispatch());
```

Mi controlador **LoginController** está cargando la función **login** como se muestra anteriormente, deberia de obetener una respuesta basica de que se ha accedido correctamente.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Authentication;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Class\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller {
    
    public function __construct() {
        
    }

    public function login() {
        return new Request("success", "Bienvenido: {$_POST['user_data_email']}");
    }

    public function loginAuth() {
        return new Request("success", "Login Auth exitoso.");
    }
    
}
```

Al mirar mi navegador para ver la respuesta obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Console was cleared
login-auth.jsx:14 {status: 'warning', message: 'Page not found', data: Array(0)}
```

Siempre estoy entrando a mi ruta index por defecto, pero nunca accede a mis otras rutas como 'Autenticar/Ingresar', estoy presentando este problema en mi hosting **Dongee**, pero en mi localhost **xampp** no se presenta este problema.

Adjunto la información del objeto router cargado:

```
Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector Object
(
    [routeParser:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser Object
        (
            [parts:Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [reverseParts:Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [partsCounter:Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser:private] => 0
            [variables:Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [regexOffset:Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser:private] => 0
            [regexShortcuts:Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser:private] => Array
                (
                    [:i}] => :[0-9]+}
                    [:a}] => :[0-9A-Za-z]+}
                    [:h}] => :[0-9A-Fa-f]+}
                    [:c}] => :[a-zA-Z0-9+_\-\.]+}
                )

        )

    [filters:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => Array
        (
            [auth] => Closure Object
                (
                    [static] => Array
                        (
                            [obj] => App\Models\Class\Middleware Object
                                (
                                    [middlewareName:App\Models\Class\Middleware:private] => auth
                                    [objectClass:App\Models\Class\Middleware:private] => App\Http\Middleware\UserAuth
                                    [methodClass:App\Models\Class\Middleware:private] => auth
                                )

                        )

                )

            [no-auth] => Closure Object
                (
                    [static] => Array
                        (
                            [obj] => App\Models\Class\Middleware Object
                                (
                                    [middlewareName:App\Models\Class\Middleware:private] => no-auth
                                    [objectClass:App\Models\Class\Middleware:private] => App\Http\Middleware\UserAuth
                                    [methodClass:App\Models\Class\Middleware:private] => noAuth
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [staticRoutes:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [ANY] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Closure Object
                                (
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [autenticar/ingresar] => Array
                (
                    [POST] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => App\Http\Controllers\Authentication\LoginController
                                    [1] => login
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [before] => no-auth
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [regexToRoutesMap:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [reverse:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [globalFilters:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [globalRoutePrefix:Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector:private] => 
)
```

Como se observa el objeto de **RouterCollector**, Tiene cargada las respectivas rutas, pero nunca accede a ellas.

Gracias por su atención.